# Coherence length of ruby laser

Tags: laser

A Ruby laser emits 1W pulses of light with wavelength $6940 ± 10 \overset{\lower.5em\circ}{\mathrm{A}}$.

What is the coherence length of the ruby laser?

My question is that what would be the value of $∆λ$ in the formula of coherent length i.e.

Coherence length $=(λ^2) /(∆λ)$.
Will it be $10$ or $20$?

Comment: Doesn't a ruby laser emit light in the "far red spectrum"? The way you write the wavelength results in $\lambda \approx 7um$. Shouldn't this be $0.7 um$?

Comment: 20 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_length

Answer (score 1):

You have not given enough information to determine the coherence length of the laser.  Some ruby lasers have [coherence length up to 100 meters](https://www.laserfocusworld.com/home/article/16566690/ruby-laser-is-reborn-as-diodepumped-continuouswave-version).  In 1974, [1 meter of coherence length was a big achievement](https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/abstract.cfm?uri=ao-13-11-2486).

Answer (score 0):

You have stated that the Coherence length: $L = \dfrac{\lambda^2}{\Delta \lambda}$ .

I will assume that you are using the approximation for the formula:

$$L = \frac{2 \ln 2}{\pi} \frac{\lambda ^2 }{n \Delta \lambda}$$

Where $n$ is the refractive index of the medium through which the wave is propagating in and is taken as $1$ for air.  For this formula, the value of $\Delta \lambda$ corresponds to the full width half maximum (FWHM) spectral width of the source.

In optics in general the width of various peaks can be given as FWHM, $\dfrac{1}{e}$ or $\dfrac{1}{e^2}$ for various different applications.  You have not made it clear which is being used for the uncertainty you provided.  Despite this, I can say that in optical communication the standard for spectral widths is FWHM.

Answer (score 0):

The literature gives you generally the width and the wavelength of the light emission.
If $\Delta \lambda << \lambda$, you can apply the equation $l_c = \frac{\lambda^2}{\Delta \lambda}$.

Typically, the width is given in Hz or GHz. You can transform it with the relation
$\Delta \lambda = \frac{\lambda^2 \Delta \nu}{c}$.

For your case, Ruby have emission at 694.3 nm and FWHM~330 GHz. You should found something around 1 mm.

NB: A better explanation can be found in the textbook of W.T. Silfvast (ISBN: 9780521833455), where the author compares the coherence length of mercury lamp and helium-neon laser.